# Combine two lists in sharepoint and use it for ssrs reporting

Tags: sharepoint-2010

how can i create a combined list from multiple lists in share point and use that combined list/data source for SSRS reporting.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS you can perform lookup joins in the Tablix directly.

for example:

```
=Join(
      LookupSet(
                Fields!FirstList_Key.Value, 
                Fields!SecondList_Key.Value, 
                Fields!SecondList_DisplayCol.Value, 
                "Name of Second List")
      )
```

Comment: but i am having one simple column and another is lookup from another table,

Comment: You need to add both lists as datasets then

Comment: i am searching for this to make datasets of 3 lists at ssrs to show reports but not able to done.

Comment: I have dozens of reports where I join multiple lists. Create a dataset for each list. I assure you, it's perfectly do-able.

Comment: so can u direct me to do so,i am doing this since last one week,but i dont want to create 1 view from multiple list. i want to create new list by combining multiple list in share point.THANK U Paul

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239345.aspx (Create Dataset in SSRS)

Comment: i really dont want anything like this, i am having three diffrent list in a single data source and i want to coombine that 3 list into one,and bind that single list to tablix and show data in tablular report,                                                    i want all these because i have 3 list and we can bind only one list to tablix at a time. Thank Yoy

Comment: Then you need to combine the data before you create a dataset in SSRS. Alternately, bind to one list and join the other two using the code snippet in the answer above. I have a 40k row list binding with 2 list joins using the above - works well.

Comment: now i did like one parent report and onclick(action) of item opening second report.two diffrent report with two tablix and two diffrent data source. Thanks